# Disable logs from 3rd party libraries in Go

Tags: go

I want to disable logs from various 3rd party libraries which a custom  log package. I'm not able to modify the libraries directly or the log package. I've already looked at [Disable logging for 3rd party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831816/disable-logging-for-3rd-party-library) which suggests to redefine `os.Stderr` as a custom `io.Writer`. How do I implement the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38832115/18024985?

Answer (score 2):

The question you have pointed to describes a different situation from yours, where a custom logger is being used. In your case, with the standard logger, you should use [`log.SetOutput`](https://pkg.go.dev/log#SetOutput) rather than redirecting `os.Stderr`.

Comment: I took a closer look into the 3rd party libraries and they are using a custom logger, not the standard package as I initially thought.